# How to configure IPython to use gvim on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, vim, ipython

This really looks like something I should be able to find on Google, but for some reason I can't make heads or tails of it. There's the EDITOR environment variable, the ipy_user_conf.py file, the ipythonrc file, some weird thing about running gvim in server mode and a bunch of other stuff I can't wrap my head around (probably because of lack of sleep).

Is there a guide somewhere I can follow, or maybe someone can just outline the steps I need to take?

Answer (score 10):

Setting the EDITOR environment variable to 'gvim -f' seems to work.

```
set EDITOR=gvim -f
```

Answer (score 6):

1. edit file - `C:\Users\[your username]\_ipython\ipythonrc.ini`
2. replace line: `editor 0` to `editor gvim –f` (or `editor [whatever editor you_want to use and system recognize it]`)
3. save file

You may have problem that your Win doesn't recognize `gvim` as a command, you can fix it like this:

Control Panel -> System -> Advances system settings (System properties - Advanced tab) -> Enviroment Variables

In system variables edit Path and add this: `;C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\` or path that leads to **your** `gvim.exe`

Answer (score 3):

[Create a new Environment Variable in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables/284351#284351) named `EDITOR`:

1. `Win XP: Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> New`
2. `Win 7: Start -> Type in Search Programs and Files: "environment variables" -> select 'Edit environment variables for your account' -> New...`

Variable name will be `EDITOR` and the Variable value will be the file path of where the `gvim.exe` file is installed (ex. `"C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe"`)

Comment: does it have to be system or user environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work with qtconsole I had to enter

```
ipython qtconsole --ConsoleWidget.editor=gvim.bat
```

gvim.bat having been created and installed in my execution path when gvim was installed under windows. Hence, to make it permanent, the

```
c.IPythonWidget.editor = 'gvim.bat'
```

line needs to be entered in `ipython_qtconsole_config.py`.

Comment: ipython_qtconsole_config.py file doesn't exist in my ipython installation. If i create it what should the full code of the file be